# My Java program freezes on call to oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleOCIConnectionPool.getConnection for a couple of minutes

Tags: java, connection-pooling, oracle11g

I have a Java app which connects to oracle 11g. The process freezes for 2 to 3 minutes at the `oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleOCIConnectionPool.getConnection` method. It does manage to get the connection and continues without any error after the 3 minutes time though.

The weird bit of this is that the same program runs fine from a different machine when connecting to the same database.

I can't figure out what is going on here. Can any one help me out with this?

Below is the thread dump of the a sample program when it is stuck at the `getConnection` method:

```
Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (1.5.0_11-b03 mixed mode):

"Thread-9" prio=10 tid=0x00431a60 nid=0x24 runnable [0xaffff000..0xaffffb70]
        at java.lang.Thread.yield(Native Method)
        at conPoolAppl.run(conPoolAppl.java:101)

"Thread-8" prio=10 tid=0x00430e50 nid=0x23 runnable [0xb00ff000..0xb00ff9f0]
        at java.lang.Thread.yield(Native Method)
        at conPoolAppl.run(conPoolAppl.java:101)

"Thread-7" prio=10 tid=0x00460490 nid=0x22 runnable [0xb01ff000..0xb01ffa70]
        at java.lang.Thread.yield(Native Method)
        at conPoolAppl.run(conPoolAppl.java:101)

"Thread-6" prio=10 tid=0x00249320 nid=0x21 runnable [0xb02ff000..0xb02ff8f0]
        at java.lang.Thread.yield(Native Method)
        at conPoolAppl.run(conPoolAppl.java:101)

"Thread-5" prio=10 tid=0x000b7910 nid=0x20 runnable [0xb03ff000..0xb03ff970]
        at java.lang.Thread.yield(Native Method)
        at conPoolAppl.run(conPoolAppl.java:101)

"Thread-4" prio=10 tid=0x000b7128 nid=0x1f runnable [0xb04ff000..0xb04ffbf0]
        at java.lang.Thread.yield(Native Method)
        at conPoolAppl.run(conPoolAppl.java:101)

"Thread-3" prio=10 tid=0x00126a50 nid=0x1e runnable [0xb05ff000..0xb05ffc70]
        at java.lang.Thread.yield(Native Method)
        at conPoolAppl.run(conPoolAppl.java:101)

"Thread-2" prio=10 tid=0x0058bc38 nid=0x1d runnable [0xb06ff000..0xb06ffaf0]
        at java.lang.Thread.yield(Native Method)
        at conPoolAppl.run(conPoolAppl.java:101)

"Thread-1" prio=10 tid=0x00125d90 nid=0x1c runnable [0xb07ff000..0xb07ffb70]
        at java.lang.Thread.yield(Native Method)
        at conPoolAppl.run(conPoolAppl.java:101)

"Low Memory Detector" daemon prio=10 tid=0x001c5f50 nid=0x19 runnable [0x00000000..0x00000000]

"CompilerThread1" daemon prio=10 tid=0x001c4de8 nid=0x18 waiting on condition [0x00000000..0xb347e8b4]

"CompilerThread0" daemon prio=10 tid=0x001c3f70 nid=0x17 waiting on condition [0x00000000..0xb357e93c]

"AdapterThread" daemon prio=10 tid=0x001c30f8 nid=0x16 waiting on condition [0x00000000..0x00000000]

"Signal Dispatcher" daemon prio=10 tid=0x001c2388 nid=0x15 waiting on condition [0x00000000..0x00000000]

"Finalizer" daemon prio=10 tid=0x001b5b80 nid=0x14 in Object.wait() [0xb387f000..0xb387faf0]
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        - waiting on <0xe30006d8> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
        at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:116)
        - locked <0xe30006d8> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
        at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:132)
        at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:159)

"Reference Handler" daemon prio=10 tid=0x001b4e38 nid=0x13 in Object.wait() [0xb397f000..0xb397fb70]
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        - waiting on <0xe30005e8> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:474)
        at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:116)
        - locked <0xe30005e8> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)

"main" prio=10 tid=0x00036898 nid=0x1 runnable [0xffbfc000..0xffbfcf30]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CConnection.t2cConnPoolLogon(Native Method)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CConnection.processOCIConnectionPooling(T2CConnection.java:1103)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CConnection.logon(T2CConnection.java:258)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:531)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CConnection.<init>(T2CConnection.java:148)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleOCIConnection.<init>(OracleOCIConnection.java:60)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleOCIConnection.<init>(OracleOCIConnection.java:44)
        at oracle.jdbc.oci.OracleOCIConnection.<init>(OracleOCIConnection.java:35)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CDriverExtension.getConnection(T2CDriverExtension.java:49)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:503)
        at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleOCIConnectionPool.getConnection(OracleOCIConnectionPool.java:244)
        - locked <0xe3272a78> (a oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleOCIConnectionPool)
        at conPoolAppl.main(conPoolAppl.java:47)

"VM Thread" prio=10 tid=0x001b2d58 nid=0x12 runnable

"GC task thread#0 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x000b8148 nid=0x2 runnable

"GC task thread#1 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x000b8b88 nid=0x3 runnable

"GC task thread#2 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x000b95c8 nid=0x4 runnable

"GC task thread#3 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x000ba008 nid=0x5 runnable

"GC task thread#4 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x000baa48 nid=0x6 runnable

"GC task thread#5 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x000bb488 nid=0x7 runnable

"GC task thread#6 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x000bbee0 nid=0x8 runnable

"GC task thread#7 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x000bd128 nid=0x9 runnable

"GC task thread#8 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x000bdb68 nid=0xa runnable

"GC task thread#9 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x000be5a8 nid=0xb runnable

"GC task thread#10 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x000befe8 nid=0xc runnable

"GC task thread#11 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x000bfa28 nid=0xd runnable

"GC task thread#12 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x000c0468 nid=0xe runnable

"GC task thread#13 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x000c0ea8 nid=0xf runnable

"GC task thread#14 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x000c18e8 nid=0x10 runnable

"GC task thread#15 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x000c2328 nid=0x11 runnable

"VM Periodic Task Thread" prio=10 tid=0x001c71e0 nid=0x1a waiting on condition
```

Comment: What happens if you sqlplus from a cmd line?  Does it connect right away?

Comment: Yes, I get thru without any issues.

Comment: Could it be a Java version difference?  My first thought was maybe some kind of reverse look-up issue but sounds like that isn't it.

Comment: You might want to take a look at this link.  It is not exactly what you are seeing but it may give some clues. http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=951428

Comment: Merky, first of all thanks for looking at this issue.

Comment: I have compares details on both the machines,  the libraries which get loaded(using PMAP), the env config/variables, the java version, every bit of it is the same. 
But for one difference,they are two different machines in two different locations.

Comment: If these are windows boxes, could it be the firewall turned on?  I am by far not an Oracle expert so I'm kind of limited with that.  Did you try a tnsping on both machines to see if the times are roughly the same?  Since sqlplus worked ok tnsping should be ok too but never hurts to try.

Comment: They are Solaris, we kind of ruled out any issues with the Oracle machine as i am able to get thru to it from a different Solaris machine.. any thing else i could check for? :(

Comment: Geeze, been almost 10 years since I've been on a Solaris box (been stuck on Micro$oft).  If you are running licensed Oracle, I'd say your best best is to contact them.  Maybe there is some debug flag you can tweak.  Sorry, that's about all I know...  Good luck.

Comment: Are you running 10 threads in a loop doing nothing but yield? You might want to revisit this code, it puts some load on your machine.

Since you are using the OCI driver, the java stack trace does not help you to see what is going on in that native logon message. I would suggest you use truss/strace to see it on the system level. It could be a nameserver, tcp or random-generator problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use ltrace&strace (linux) or truss&dtrace (solaris) to see what the native code is doing.